# I'm having trouble with loading a font using vgafix.otf/ttf/fon

Tags: java, fonts, paintcomponent

So I'm loading a font and printing with it - however, it REFUSES to work. I've tried lots of things and am finally coming to you guys. Here is the code that loads:

```
public Font loadFont(){
    Font font = null;
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("vgafix.otf"));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return font;
}
```

And here is the definition of the font variable and its print

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g, String dialogue){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    int x = 75;
    int y = 75;
    Font fixedsys = loadFont();
    g2.drawString(dialogue,75,75);
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the exception. At minimum log it or call `e.printStacktrace()` in your catch-block; then add the full stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never catch Exception.  There are many subclasses of Exception which are designed to let you know that you have made a programming error (like NullPointerException).  Silencing them will not make your code work, it will just make it impossible to know what you did wrong.

You should only catch the exception types which you need to catch.  Assuming you're using Java 7 or later, you should write `catch (FontFormatException | IOException e)`.

Second, **never** write an empty catch block.  Your situation perfectly illustrates why you should not do that:  you have completely hidden all of the information that would have told you what went wrong.  Furthermore, silencing the exception did not help you in any way.  What good is returning a null Font?

The correct thing to do in your catch block is to make your code fail loudly and immediately, so that you know what's wrong and can fix it.  This is sometimes called a *fail-fast* design.  It typically looks something like this:

```
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Third, you are free to define whatever public methods you want, but a `paintComponent` method with *two* arguments will never be called by Swing.  Only paintComponent(Graphics) is called by Swing.  A good way to catch this mistake is to put [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) before your method;  that tells the compiler that you meant to override a method that exists with the same signature in an inherited class.  It there is no inherited method with that signature, the compiler will inform you of your mistake.

If you are calling your two-argument method from paintComponent(Graphics), then the method is fine.  Otherwise, you need to make `dialogue` a (private) field in your class, and change the method signature of paintComponent to match the method it is supposed to be overriding.

Fourth, you are not doing anything with the font returned from calling loadFont().  Just doing `Font fixedsys = loadFont();` does not change how text is drawn.  You need to tell the Graphics object to use it:

```
Font fixedsys = loadFont();
g2.setFont(fixedsys);
```

Fifth, `new File("vgafix.otf")` refers to a *relative file name.*  Every process has its own *current directory,* including the Java runtime.  Files which do not start with a [file separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) (or drive letter followed by a file separator) are relative files, assumed to be found by prepending the current directory to their paths.  In your case, it means vgafix.otf must exist in the Java runtime process's current directory.

If, after following the above recommendations so that the exception is seen, you find that a FileNotFoundException is occurring, you probably have run your program in such a way that the current directory isn't where you expected it to be.

Since it's not always obvious what that current directory is, you should do something more reliable.  The easiest solution is to use an *absolute file name,* like this:

```
new File("C:\\Users\\VGR\\Downloads\\vgafix.otf");
```

Or, on non-Windows machines:

```
new File("/home/vgr/Downloads/vgafix.otf");
```

But that's not a portable approach, and certainly won't work if you ever want to deliver your application as a .jar file.  Ideally, the font file should be in the same package as the class which loads it.  Then your code can do:

```
try (InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("vgafix.otf")) {
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream);
}
```